# jQuery get object's element by the string name of the attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

```
$.each ( columns, function ( index, value ){
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var text = document.createTextNode( data.attr( value ) );
    td.appendChild(text);
    tr.appendChild(td);
});
```

I have data.
I have `value = "name"`

I can't do `data.name`, I need to do the equivalent using the string. I tried  `.attr( value )` but that didn't work.

Comment: can you create fiddle or post what you have and what you want to do with it?

Comment: and if data.name don't work because data it not a object then you can try access via array data['name'] ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - Good edit there! Your example was way too long, see [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @daremachine https://jsfiddle.net/c19y2e27/

Comment: @daremachine this was it. Make it an answer and I'll select it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access to object properties in two ways.

With `[dot]` chaining or `like an array`.

If you have a problem with access to object property or your object property is variable then you use array access.

Simple example

```
var data = {
    aaa: {
        items: [
            { id: 1, name: "test" },
            { id: 2, name: "test2" }
        ]
    },
    bbb: {
        items: [
            { id: 1, name: "test" }
        ]
    }
};
```

In example below 
if you want to set empty array in specific object and your decisive key is a variable then you can't use [dot] chaining because variable is not affected. Then you can use array access.

```
// set aaa as bbb
var aaa = 'bbb';

// WORK aaa is bbb
data[aaa]['items'] = [];

// DOES NOT WORK PROPERLY aaa is not bbb but still aaa
data.aaa.items = [];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Your example does not work. If you type it in your browser console, it will obviously throw an error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`, because `data[0][name]` is equivalent to `data[0].aaa` and since your object does not have an `aaa` field it returns `undefined`... And trying to read a property of `undefined` throws a `TypeError`. Please check your examples before posting. @James Please check that the answer is actually correct before accepting.

Comment: @Kyll thank you for your advice. I edited it. Now is it complete and what i wanted to say.